# How to cache files from FileField to avoid repeat (Django, DRF)

Tags: django, python-3.x, caching, django-rest-framework

Summary:

I want to cache files that are read in from a FileField in order to optimize performance of the DRF api.

Background:

The system allows users to upload data files (csv-like) and stores a link to those files using a FileField (django/djangorestframework backends).

The model object has additional methods that act on the data stored in the FileField file... i.e. get column names, number of rows, specific data queries (col A from ix 0 -> 10)

Each of these methods requires the file to be read in prior to returning data.

I'm finding that the required loading and reloading of the file object for every query is costing a ton of CPU & response time.

Is there a smart way to cache files that have been read in already (with a timeout) and have django prevent reloading files that are already cached?

I've seen some info about memcached but that seems to be more geared toward caching specific API calls rather than the underlying DB objects/data.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

After doing some more digging I found this helpful link about simple cacheing examples in python in general (https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/02/25/python-an-intro-to-caching/)

Using that approach I created a property in the model class itself for reading in the data like the following:

```
FILECACHE = TableDataCache()  # Class implemented similar to the link above

class TableData(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False, upload_to='table_data')
    # other fields created here

    @property
    def data(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        if FILECACHE.has_key(self.file.path):
            return FILECACHE[self.file.path]
        data = pd.read_csv(self.file.path)
        FILECACHE.update(self.file.path, data)
        return data
```

If anyone can think of a simpler approach I'm open to suggestions but for now this solves my problem.